# Simplify css selectors with the same parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
.content p, .content ul, .content h1 {
       text-indent: 35px;
}
```

Are there any shortcuts for this selector, like `.content p, ul, h1 {}`?

Comment: No, there isn't. Unless you use some other tool than CSS, for example LESS.

Comment: +1 for a CSS pre-compiler like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (I like SASS, personally)

Comment: thanks to all, I'll try one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With normal CSS you do not have a choice.

With CSS compilers like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) you can write something like that:

```
.content {
    .p, ul, h1 {
        text-indent: 35px;
    }
}
```

I nowadays highly recommend using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) which makes writing CSS so much more fun.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `:matches()` functional pseudo-class in [Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) (aka CSS 4):

```
.content :matches(p, ul, h1) {
  text-indent: 25px;
}
```

However, it isn't supported by any browser yet. But there are `:-webkit-any()` and `:-moz-any()` that bring the same functionality to Chrome and Firefox respectively.

Comment: +1 for mentioning an upcoming standard. Sadly it does not solve any real world problems, yet.